# Form in C# returns DialogResult.Cancel to Parent When It is Minimized

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form "Main" and in Main I am creating another form which I use .ShowDialog() to display it.  I do this because I don't want the rest of the code to in Main to execute until after the new form is completed.  I am allowing a user to minimize the new form to system tray.

The problem: When the form gets minimized it is returning DialogResult.Cancel to the Main form that called it, causing the next line to run early.

Code to create form from Main form:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < lvAll.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
    {
        this.Hide();
        this.run = new RunProfile(this.profiles[lvAll.SelectedItems[i].Text]);
        DialogResult result = run.ShowDialog();
        MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());
    }
```

In the new form a user will get a list of files that copy... now the user can continue and copy those files and I would expect to return a result of OK and if not I assume they are going to cancel and return Cancel...

Is my only recourse to return Abort from the new form if a user specifies a cancel and assume that a cancel is someone trying to minimize?  This just seems odd

Comment: Minimize should not cause it to return. I tried in an empty VB.NET project and was not able to reproduce your issue. Please try it in an empty C# project and let us know if the issue persists. If you are able to reproduce, please also include a link to your sample project, so we can try on our machines.

Comment: Interesting problem, but I think it can be avoided by rethinking your approach. What you're trying to do is very unusual behavior for a Windows application, and thus not recommended. Well behaved software is consistent and predictable. I suggest not allowing the modal dialog to be minimized at all. If you must allow it to minimize, then keep it visible in the taskbar.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a quote from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  regarding ShowDialog:

> When this method is called, the code following it is not executed
>   until after the dialog box is closed.

After further reading it does state the X does not close the form but hides it and so you must dispose of it:

> When a form is displayed as a modal dialog box, clicking the Close
>   button (the button with an X in the top-right corner of the form)
>   causes the form to be hidden and the DialogResult property to be set
>   to DialogResult.Cancel. The Close method is not automatically called
>   when the user clicks the Close button of a dialog box or sets the
>   value of the DialogResult property. Instead, the form is hidden and
>   can be shown again without creating a new instance of the dialog box.
>   Because of this behavior, you must call the Dispose method of the form
>   when the form is no longer needed by your application.

It seems this same issues applies to minimizing a userform as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could handle this in a number of ways, one way is like what follows:

```
    MainTestForm mainTestForm = new MainTestForm();

    if (mainTestForm.ShowDialog() != System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        return;
    }
```

You must set the DialogResult state when you close the form like

```
    this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is entirely by design.  When you hide a modal dialog, the user doesn't have any way to get back to the program.  Dialogs don't have a taskbar button and the rest of the windows in the app are disabled so cannot be activated.  The only recourse the user would have is to kill your program with Task Manager.

So Winforms does the logical thing, it automatically closes the dialog to avoid this UI trap.  And of course you'll get DialogResult.Cancel.

Use proper UI design, a dialog should always have its MinimizeBox property set to False.

Comment: Hans what would be the appropriate alternative then to handle this situation?  Im modeling my program after another that does a similar task (popping up new form after the first completes while allowing minimize to systray)

Comment: Just don't make it a dialog, I'd say.  Nothing in that comment suggests that it should be one.  Just display it with Show() instead.  Implement the "minimize to systray" feature in the FormClosing event handler.

Comment: The Show form is inside a loop it should display new forms consecutively not concurrently - if I use .Show() instead I could get multiple forms opening all at once when I only want 1 to show at a time.

Comment: Again no hint that ShowDialog is appropriate or necessary.  If you want to display another form when the current one closes then just subscribe the FormClosing/Closed event.  Think this through for a bit before you post your next comment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with that. However, to get the Dialog to return anything else, you have to set it in the form's (Dialog's) DialogResult property before the form is closed.

You may also use the Form_Closing event of the dialog to set the DialogResult property to what you want. This is done before the form closes.